# target input field and submit button by type and name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I'm using a Jquery code to check if an e-mail input field is empty before sending the form.

here is my e-mail input html :

```
<input class="sml_emailinput" type="email" value="" placeholder="votre adresse e-mail" name="sml_email"></input>
```

and here is my submit button :

```
<input class="btn sml_submitbtn" type="submit" value="OK" name="submit"></input>
```

it works fine with this code :

```
function submit_newsletter(){

    var $submit = $("input[type=submit]"),
        $inputs = $("input[type=email]");

    function checkEmpty() {
        return $inputs.filter(function() {
            return !$.trim(this.value);
        }).length === 0;
    }

    $inputs.on('blur', function() {
        $submit.prop("disabled", !checkEmpty());
    }).blur();

}
```

the problem is that I'm using other input fields on my website and so I need to target those two specific field only using input type and input name.

I tried many ways of doin it and I really don't understand why it's not working.

here the code I tried :

```
function submit_newsletter(){

    var $submit = $("input[type='submit', name='submit']"),
        $inputs = $("input[type='email', name='sml_email']"); 



    function checkEmpty() {
        return $inputs.filter(function() {
            return !$.trim(this.value);
        }).length === 0;
    }

    $inputs.on('blur', function() {
        $submit.prop("disabled", !checkEmpty());
    }).blur();

}
```

can anybody help me with this ?
I can't change the html of the two inputs because it's generated by a plugin.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you need is

`$('input[type="x"][name="y"]')`

Answer (score 0):

Try it using

```
$('input[type="x"][name="y"]')
```